# Index out of bound for array in OPL CPLEX

Tags: variables, cplex, opl

I am writing a code in opl cplex space, but I am facing **"Index out of bound for array "x(8)": 2."** error, thank you for helping me.
I have a loop in this code, in each step the variables of the previous step must be fixed for the next step.

```
{int}s={};
range M = 1..5;
tuple link {
    key int N;
    int     fromnode;
    int     tonode;
};
main{
   var source = new IloOplModelSource("subset.mod");
   var cplex = new IloCplex();
   var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
   
   var output = new Array(3);
   for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
     output[i] = new Array(3);
     for(var j=6; j<=12; j++) {
       output[i][j] = 0.0;
     }
   }
 
       for(var iter=6;iter<=12;iter++)
       {
      cplex.tilim=300;
      
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
      var data= new IloOplDataElements();
      data.N=thisOplModel.s;
      data.N.add(iter);
    data.M=thisOplModel.M;
    data.Links=thisOplModel.Links;
    opl.addDataSource(data);
    opl.generate();
   if (iter!=6){
     for (var r in data.N){ 
            for (var k in data.M){
            if (output[k][r]==1){
       opl.x[k][r].LB=output[k][r];
       opl.x[k][r].UB=output[k][r];
     writeln("xds[",k,"]","[",r,"]"," = ",output[k][r]);
     }}}   
   }         
    
      opl.postProcess(); 
   for (var k in data.M){
      for (var r in data.N){
       output[k][r]=opl.x[k][r].solutionValue;
     }
   }   
  data.end();    
  opl.end();   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can help me, I need an answer to this question, please

Comment: If you want people to help you, try giving a bit more info on what you have tried so far to investigate the issue. What debugging have you done? The error message sugests that the array index out of bounds is for array 'x', but that array isn't even in the code you show above, it appears to be in the OPL model (e.g. opl.x[k][r]) so we have no idea how it was declared.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, the variable definition in my model is as follows: ```{int} M=...;
//**
{int} N = ...;
tuple link {
    key int N;
    int     fromnode;
    int     tonode;
} 
{link} Links = ...;

dvar boolean x[M][N];```

Comment: Either the array is declared the wrong size or the indices used for accessing it are calculated wrong. So we know that x[M][N] is a 2D array of boolean variables, but we don't know the sizes M and N as those are in the data file. Or is M supposed to be the same M as in the code above? When does the error happen - which iteration of the model does it fail on? Have you looked at the values of the array indices as the code runs, and do they match what you would expect? Did you try debugging through the code or just printing the values of the indices just before they get used? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I checked all these things but the problem is not solved :( the definition of N in data file: ```Links = {
//  N    from  to  EP  LD   I     dr
  <1 , 1 ,   7>
  <2 , 1 ,   8 >
  <3 , 2 ,   8 >
  <4 , 8 ,   2 >
  <5 , 3 ,   6 >
  <6 , 5 ,   4 >
  <7 , 3 ,   4 >
};```